# js searching for pattern doesnt work

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

i used a pattern to make sure that if there are running same char than 3 occurrence in php code and its working but when i tried it in javascript it didn't work any idea?

```
if (!(/(.)\\1{2}/.test(string))) {
  console.log('there are no running 3 chars occur in the string');
} else{
  console.log('there are 3 running same char occur in the string');
}
```

the console give me "here are no running 3 chars occur in the string" although the string is "iii"

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have escaped the `\` in the pattern. So it is trying to match any letter followed by two `\` characters. Try updating your pattern to `/(.)\1{2}/`.

```
if (!(/(.)\1{2}/.test(string))){
    console.log('there are no running 3 chars occur in the string');
} else { 
    console.log('there are 3 running same char occur in the string');
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but this pattern works in php by preg_match. why not working in js by .test any idea? ... i would like reference that can help me more with patterns because i really want to learn about it more. thanks alot

Comment: Because they are different implementations. Why are you surprised? Start here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions